# Is "que" a relative pronoun in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire

In the sentence "Mon père dit que je suis trop jeune pour avoir de l’argent", is "que" a relative pronoun or is it something else entirely?

Comment: Dans cette phrase, je crois que c'est une **conjonction de subordination**. Attendons des réponses plus précises.

Answer (score 5):

> Mon père dit que je suis trop jeune pour avoir de l’argent.

In that sentence,

> je suis trop jeune pour avoir de l'argent

is used as a ***subordonnée complétive*** (it means that it completes the sentence "*Mon père dit*"). Between the two, is the [***conjonction de subordination***](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-31131.php) "*que*". See it as a link between the two statements (the first as the main one, the second as the subordinate).

---

The [relative pronoun](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-31128.php) "*que*" is something different. It refers to the subject of the sentence.

> La banane ***que*** je mange est un peu trop mûre.